# Pass a random ID as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I am really new o programming and I apologize in advance if by any change my question seems a little silly.

I have two functions, the first one is creating a div, inserting it inside another div and assigning it a random ID generated by the Math.random() method. The second one is getting this brand new element by its ID and setting a style on it.

But in order to this function works properly I need to get this new ID with the 'getElementById()' method. I thought that I could pass it as a parameter through the interFrame function, but it is being recognized as 'null'.

I already made my research and tryed all I was able to think but I just couldn't find an objectve answer.

You'll see on this pen a button and when you click on it,a blue block will be showed, I want that this block goes down automatically after the button has been clicked.

https://codepen.io/WegisSilveira/pen/PMPoaR

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var py;
var dy;
var vel;

    function addBlock() {
        dy = 0.4;
        py = 0;
        vel = 0.1;

        var ID = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "block";
        div.setAttribute('id', ID);
        field.appendChild(div);
        interFrame(ID);    
    }

    function interFrame(id) {
        var block = document.getElementById(id);
        tmp = requestAnimationFrame(interFrame);
        py += dy + vel;

        block.style.top = py + "px";

        if (py >= 675) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(tmp);
        }
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', addBlock);

    <body>
            <div id="field">
                <button type="submit" id="btn">TesteAdd</button>
            </div>


        </body>
```

Comment: can you also post the HTML so that its easy for someone to help you.

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph I don't have any element, just the parent div. I am inserting new divs inside it and using the variable ID to generate the id. Using the devtools I can see it is working. The reason I am trying to pass this same number as an argument is actually to the getElementById receive the same id. I don't know if I am being clear, sorry about that

Comment: What is null? `id` in interframe or the value of `block` when you run getElementByID?

Comment: In your code `field` isn't defined. Are you defining it elsewhere? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @alberto montalesi the second one, when I run getElementById. The id in the interframe function is receiving the value

Comment: @H77 yes, all variables are fine. I defined all of them. There isn't any other error besides the 'null' thing

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I just added it on the code

Comment: @Monstro have you inspected the page and confirmed that the `div` get's added to the page? Or that it actually get's and `id

Comment: In the code as posted, `dy`, `py`, and `vel` will be undefined inside `interframe`.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet the variables are declared. I just correct it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet but OP has declared it globally, which means its accessible.

Comment: @Nidhin: only in an edit since I made my comment.  This is a moving target

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes yes, got you :)

Comment: @Nidhin Sorry about the mess, man. I am really new on all of this. I'll try to be more clear the next times and pay more atention to the details.

Comment: @Monstro: before the next time, please read some of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the article on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Scott Sauyet of course, I'll do that for sure. It will make things much more simple. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can pass the `div` instance rather than to seacrch for the ID itself as both refers to the same el. Now, in your `requestAnimationFrame` callback, you will need to pass the parameters because `interFrame` needs them to properly work.

**Demo**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var random;
var py;
var dy;
var vel;
var block;
var ID;

function interFrame(div, id) {
  var block = div;
  tmp = requestAnimationFrame(interFrame.bind(this, div, id));
  py += dy + vel;

  block.style.top = py + "px";

  if (py >= 100) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(tmp);
  }
  block.innerHTML = "inner" + id;
}

function addBlock() {
  dy = 0.4;
  py = 0;
  vel = 0.1;

  var ID = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "block";
  div.setAttribute('id', ID);
  field.appendChild(div);
  interFrame(div, ID);
}



btn.addEventListener('click', addBlock);
```

```css
#field {
  height: 750px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.block {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 262.5px;
  position: absolute;
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <button type="submit" id="btn" onclick="addBlock();">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried that, but in this case the 'top' property is undefined

Comment: I just saw you asked for the HTML code, but it is just a div.

Comment: Then I would guess that your `field` variable doesn't represent something actually on the DOM.  Could it be a document fragment?  Something else?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet it is the parent div. just that. I edited the question and put the html there

Comment: @Monstro Just check the demo, I have edited my post. You can see in the console that the div has style set to `top:10px`. It may be some typo from your side,just double check your implementation. Thanks

Comment: I just did. I was exactling trying it right now. And yes, you're right, It works, but just once, I don't know why, but when I add ''requestAnimationFrame" top is set as undefined.

Comment: `tmp = requestAnimationFrame(interFrame);` -> how can this work? are you sure that you need to pass `interFrame` the function? or should it be `tmp = requestAnimationFrame(div);`

Comment: Yes, because I need the equation 'py += dy + vel' being incremented repeatedly.

Comment: but still what do you achieve by passing a function? Can you show what `requestAnimationFrame` look like? I have edited the demo snippet which now increments your `py += dy + vel`

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph Yes, of course. I just created a pen, it is on my question. You'll see a button and when you click on it,a blue block will be showed, I want that this block goes down automatically after the button has been clicked.

Comment: @Monstro all good, just check the demo now, I have edited it to achieve your result.

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph It is working perfectly. Thank you very much for the patience. I was going crazy about it

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph If it isn't to much trouble could you explain to me what you did? I already studied a little about 'bind' and 'this', but I am not sure how it is working in this scenario. If you can't there is no problem, you already helped me a lot. :) Thank you!

Comment: `bind` and `call` are really good at setting the `this` value of a function. In your case, it isn't that relevant as your function just needs the right parameters.

Comment: Ok, I see. I just read your edit and it made things more clear to me. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version without all the global variables:

```js
function addBlock() {
    var field = document.getElementById("field");
    var ID = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "block";
    div.setAttribute('id', ID);
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('node: ' + ID))
    field.appendChild(div);
    interFrame(ID);    
}

function interFrame(id) {
    var block = document.getElementById(id);
    var tmp;
    var py = 0;
    var dy = 0.4;
    var vel = 0.1;

    function frame() {
        py += dy + vel;
        block.style.top = py + "px";

        if (py < 675) {
            tmp = requestAnimationFrame(frame)
        }
    
    }
    tmp = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', addBlock);
```

```css
#field {
  height: 750px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.block {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 262.5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <button type="submit" id="btn">TesteAdd</button>
</div>
```

As to why your code wasn't working, `requestAnimationFrame` was calling `interFrame`, but when it does so, it doesn't pass the id you needed.  It only received that id on the first invocation.  Here I use a helper function, `frame` which already has `block`, `py`, `dy`, and `vel` in scope an doesn't need to reinitialize them.

Comment: I see. It seems so simple now. Your explanation made things really clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just tried it on my code and it is exactly what I needed. You kind of answered two more questions I am sure would come up. :)